# c++ compile time heterogeneous array, python style

Tags: c++

I've got a solution to a problem in c++, but I find myself writing this:

```
dosomething(1,"value1");
dosomething(2,"somethingelse");
dosomething(3,"notthesame");
dosomething(7,"wahetevr");
dosomething(5,"yeah");
```

and it works fine, but it's rather long...and getting longer. but the two sets of values are compile time only.

In python I would have created a tuple of the two values in a list and then just foreached over them. Is there any way to create a light weight heterogenous array of the two values? I'm trying to avoid creating a type and throwing them in as well as trying to avoid using a library since I've kept the libraries I've used to zero so far.

I would rather not create two arrays of the two value sets, it's too easy to get them out of sync.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: You are using the `std` library though, right?

Comment: nope haven't needed it yet.

Comment: That's rather foolish, it solves a lot of common problems for you.

Comment: I'm not using something because I haven't needed it's features so it's foolish not to include it until I need it?

There are plenty of libraries. Why would I want to add one library only to have to remove it if I ultimately go in a different direction and then end up with overlapping utility libraries? I see that a lot in projects and it always makes things difficult to understand / maintain.

Comment: Every standard compliant compiler provides an implementation of the standard library. There's no overlap. It only makes your project easier to maintain. It is C++.

Comment: so boost doesn't have things in the std....Or how about QT's QPair, it's not in the std?

Yes, they overlap, yes they can even work together, and no I do not want to have half the code using QPair and the other half using std::map. Is this something I could understand? yes. Is it something I think should happen? no. I like my codebases, especially for ones I'm mostly just messing around with, to be consistent in style and functionality. It's not necessary by any means, but since this is mostly just me pleasing an itch, I'll do things my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no heterogenous or associative array literal in the core C++ language like `dict`s in Python**.

Storing and retrieving key-value pairs is a job for a *map* in C++. [**`std::map`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a part of the Standard Library, included with every standards-compliant compiler and should not be overlooked!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{   
    // Typedefs make code more readable:
    typedef std::map<int, std::string> lookup_t;

    // Create map:
    lookup_t lookup;

    // Insert information:
    lookup[1] = "value1";
    lookup[2] = "somethingelse";
    lookup[3] = "notthesame";
    lookup[7] = "wahetevr";
    lookup[5] = "yeah";

    // Random access:
    std::cout << "3 -> " << lookup[3] << std::endl;

    // Sequential access:
    for (lookup_t::iterator i = lookup.begin(), end = lookup.end(); i != end; ++i)
    {   
        std::cout << i->first // key
            << " -> "
            << i->second // value
            << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Similar constructs exist in other third-party libraries, such as [Qt's `QMap`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmap.html), and the various maps in [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/container/history_and_reasons.html), and less portable ones such as Microsoft's [`CMap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

In the interests of efficiency and portability, I would opt for the standard map unless there was a compelling reason to take an alternative approach.

Comment: ...not always available - e.g. in Kernel

Comment: Sure. There's nothing about this question that suggests kernel development is the subject.

Comment: it's not kernel, but i'm trying to avoid any library until I have to use one, mostly because If I decide to go with QT for the GUI i don't want half the code base using std::map or boost::tuple and the rest using QPair.

This isn't important enough for me to decide on any library at all yet.

the general consensus is 'a library is required' which is fine, but the question wasn't 'can this be done in *a* library' the question was 'can this be done without a library' and the answer is apparently no.

Comment: Can this be done without a library? Yes, it can. But the time you spend reinventing `std::map` and getting something working is likely to be long; longer than making your map compatible with Qt. As I understand it, Qt can be configured with standard library compatibility. In short, if you have `std::map` available to you and you choose not to use it, you're wasting your time and that of whomever you're creating code for.

Comment: Or, I can do what I'm doing and put //TODO: in the file, skip changing it from what it is, and when I have my first library requirement I'll just change it then.


Reimplementing, or selecting a library for one single minor thing and then being locked in is madness. Not to mention wastes my time *removing* it when/if I select some other library in the future.

Comment: If you can be productive and write efficient code without using ***standard library*** code, then more power to your elbow, sir. Personally, I find `//TODO`s to be a a waste of my time. I've updated my answer and hope it answers your question.

Comment: Oh it was! My question basically was 'can this be done without a library' and the answer was 'nope, but here are some libraries which do this'. 

Your answer was by far the most complete, this is why I accepted yours. Looking at the point I am in my project I will probably end up using QT's (since I'm hesitantly thinking QT's gui is where I'm ending up). Otherwise I would be using the std (rather than boost since I currently have no need of boosts other components).

Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your compiler. If you have a modern compiler you can use the C++ 11 [`tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) type. For example:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::string>> tuples = 
    { 
        std::make_tuple(1, "value1"), 
        std::make_tuple(2, "somethingelse"), 
        ... 
    };

for(auto item : tuples)
    dosomething(get<0>(item), get<1>(item));
```

If your compiler does not support tuples or range based for, you can use boost tuples and BOOST_FOREACH. They have a similar interface, just google it :)

Alex.

Comment: I am aware of the boost library. I'm trying to avoid adding it if possible.

I'm sadly not using a c++ 11 compiler =/

Comment: You can always write your own generic tuple class. It's not as hard as you think. Template specialization is your friend.

Comment: @ArthurIce then you can use `std::pair<int, std::string>`. This is available in C++03.

Comment: @juanchopanza, you are correct indeed. You can also write an answer to get the reputation points :)

Answer (score 1):

That's what [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) is for. It's essentially an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

just use `boost` tuple library

here is the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html

EDIT:

Also you have http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/

Comment: ..and that was explicitly not what I wanted to do. I would rather just have the 30 or 40 items in a line than to add a library I'm not using.

Comment: Well, boost is kind of "a must" for any serious c++ development. But can't make you use libraries.

Comment: There are plenty of libraries besides just boost. std, QT, etc etc. i'm just trying to avoid committing to *any* of them until I have to, in which case I'll then figure out what I will need. I'm still just doing a bunch of the *core* calculating of the project so there is no sense committing yet over anything this minor.